# GET-ACL file owner without domain path

Tags: powershell, acl

I need a quick way to pull a file's owner using GET-ACL and create a variable with the username and not the domain path. Trying to simply replace the domain didn't work.

```
$user = GET-ACL $lastImage.FullName | Select Owner
$user = $user.Replace('ANT\', '')
```

Provides this error:

```
Method invocation failed because [Selected.System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity] does not contain a method named 'Replace'.
At line:1 char:1
+ $user = $user.Replace('ANT\', '')
```

I know that the replace string is correct because this works:

```
$user = 'ANT\username'
$user = $user.Replace('ANT\', '')
```

I also tried using split with no success:

```
$user = GET-ACL | Select Owner
$user.Split('\')[1]
```

And this, which works but the output contains unwanted headers:

```
$user = Get-ChildItem $lastImage.FullName | select @{Name='Owner';E=
{(($_.GetAccessControl().Owner.Split('\'))[1])}}
```

Does anyone know of an easy way to get just the user name as a variable using GET-ACL? If not, is there a better cmdlet I should be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
$user = GET-ACL $lastImage.FullName | Select Owner
```

to this:

```
$user = GET-ACL $lastImage.FullName | Select -ExpandProperty Owner
```

**Explanation:**

You are trying to replace a `PSCustomObject` type instead of a string, the `.Replace()` method is a string method, this is why you get an error say `does not contain a method named 'Replace'.`

When you add the `-ExpandProperty` you will get the string value, then the replace method will work.

See: `-ExpandProperty` further explanation on [MSDN Blogs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/09/13/select-expandproperty-propertyname/)

Comment: Along these lines, `Get-Acl | Get-Member` is a nice way of seeing what is available to you since sometimes the expanded string isn't quite what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Change `$user.Replace('ANT\', '')` to `$user.Owner.Replace('ANT\', '')`. Since what you are doing is referencing the Owner property of the object. You can then remove the `| Select Owner` from the first line since it wouldn't be needed.

So as follows:

```
$user = Get-Acl $lastImage.FullName
$user = $user.Owner.Replace('ANT\', '')
```